# SVG filter element clips the referencing path

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm finding that svg filter elements have a problem when used with path elements.  When a path element has instructions like this `d="M28,46L28,23L77,23"` to render two orthogonal lines, it works fine with the filter and the drop shadow renders as expected, but as the length of one of the lines approaches zero, a problem emerges: the path element, including any marker, start to get clipped by the filter.
I don't understand what's going on exactly, but it seems that the bounding box for the filter, which is a percentage of the path bounding box, collapses to zero height and this somehow clips the referencing path element.  As soon as the path bounding box becomes zero, the problem disappears (at least it does in Chrome and Opera...).

I couldn't find any bug reports about this, can anyone explain this behaviour and/or suggest a way to deal with it?

```js
  var width = 300,
    height = 100,
    constant = 10;

  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  var defs = svg.append("defs");
  var markerW = 8,
    markerH = 6,
    marker = defs.append('marker')
    .attr('id', "triangle")
    .attr('viewBox', "0 0 10 10")
    .attr('refX', "0")
    .attr('refY', 5)
    .attr('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth')
    .attr('markerWidth', markerW)
    .attr('markerHeight', markerH)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')

  var path = marker.append('path')
    .attr('d', "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z")

  // create filter with id #drop-shadow
  // height=130% so that the shadow is not clipped
  var filter = defs.append("filter")
    .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
    .attr({
      "height": "200%",
      "width": "200%",
      x: "-50%",
      y: "-50%"
    })
    /*.style({opacity: 0.5})*/
  ;

  // SourceAlpha refers to opacity of graphic that this filter will be applied to
  // convolve that with a Gaussian with standard deviation 3 and store result
  // in blur
  filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
    .attr("stdDeviation", 1)
    .attr("result", "blur");

  // translate output of Gaussian blur to the right and downwards with 2px
  // store result in offsetBlur
  var feOffset = filter.append("feOffset")
    .attr("in", "blur")
    .attr("dx", 2)
    .attr("dy", 2)
    .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

  // overlay original SourceGraphic over translated blurred opacity by using
  // feMerge filter. Order of specifying inputs is important!
  var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

  feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
  feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

  var connector = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) {
      return Math.round(d[0])
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return Math.round(d[1])
    });

  function linkPath(d) {
    var x1 = d[0][0],
      y1 = d[0][1],
      x2 = d[1][0],
      y2 = d[1][1];
    return connector([
      [x1, y1],
      [x1, y2],
      [x2, y2]
    ]);
  }
  var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data([
      [
        [10, 40],
        [200, 40]
      ]
    ])
    .enter()
    .append('path').attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#triangle)')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")
    .attr("d", linkPath)

  function start() {
    var t = 3000;
    link.data([
        [
          [10, 60],
          [200, 40]
        ]
      ])
      .transition().delay(t / 3).duration(t).ease("linear")
      .attr("d", linkPath)
      .each("end", function() {
        link.data([
            [
              [10, 40],
              [200, 40]
            ]
          ])
          .transition().duration(t).ease("linear")
          .attr("d", linkPath)
          .each("end", function() {
            link.data([
                [
                  [10, 20],
                  [200, 40]
                ]
              ])
              .transition().delay(t / 3).duration(t).ease("linear")
              .attr("d", linkPath)
              .each("end", function() {
                link.data([
                    [
                      [10, 40],
                      [200, 40]
                    ]
                  ])
                  .transition().duration(t).ease("linear")
                  .attr("d", linkPath)
                  .each("end", start)
              })
          })
      })
  };
  start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Filter Effects Region](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion), which is set using the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` attributes, describe the area over which the filter applies.

If you define it in terms of percentages, it will shrink as the path's bounding box shrinks.  Even if you use a large percentage, it will collapse to zero when the bounding box does.  That's the reason for your clipping.

The good news is that you don't have to use percentages. Just specify a filter region in proper coordinates.

```js
  var width = 300,
    height = 100,
    constant = 10;

  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  var defs = svg.append("defs");
  var markerW = 8,
    markerH = 6,
    marker = defs.append('marker')
    .attr('id', "triangle")
    .attr('viewBox', "0 0 10 10")
    .attr('refX', "0")
    .attr('refY', 5)
    .attr('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth')
    .attr('markerWidth', markerW)
    .attr('markerHeight', markerH)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')

  var path = marker.append('path')
    .attr('d', "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z")

  // create filter with id #drop-shadow
  // height=100 pixels so that the shadow is not clipped
  var filter = defs.append("filter")
    .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
    .attr("filterUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
    .attr({
      "height": "100",
      "width": "300",
      x: "-50",
      y: "-50"
    })
    /*.style({opacity: 0.5})*/
  ;

  // SourceAlpha refers to opacity of graphic that this filter will be applied to
  // convolve that with a Gaussian with standard deviation 3 and store result
  // in blur
  filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
    .attr("stdDeviation", 1)
    .attr("result", "blur");

  // translate output of Gaussian blur to the right and downwards with 2px
  // store result in offsetBlur
  var feOffset = filter.append("feOffset")
    .attr("in", "blur")
    .attr("dx", 2)
    .attr("dy", 2)
    .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

  // overlay original SourceGraphic over translated blurred opacity by using
  // feMerge filter. Order of specifying inputs is important!
  var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

  feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
  feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

  var connector = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) {
      return Math.round(d[0])
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return Math.round(d[1])
    });

  function linkPath(d) {
    var x1 = d[0][0],
      y1 = d[0][1],
      x2 = d[1][0],
      y2 = d[1][1];
    return connector([
      [x1, y1],
      [x1, y2],
      [x2, y2]
    ]);
  }
  var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data([
      [
        [10, 40],
        [200, 40]
      ]
    ])
    .enter()
    .append('path').attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#triangle)')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")
    .attr("d", linkPath)

  function start() {
    var t = 3000;
    link.data([
        [
          [10, 60],
          [200, 40]
        ]
      ])
      .transition().delay(t / 3).duration(t).ease("linear")
      .attr("d", linkPath)
      .each("end", function() {
        link.data([
            [
              [10, 40],
              [200, 40]
            ]
          ])
          .transition().duration(t).ease("linear")
          .attr("d", linkPath)
          .each("end", function() {
            link.data([
                [
                  [10, 20],
                  [200, 40]
                ]
              ])
              .transition().delay(t / 3).duration(t).ease("linear")
              .attr("d", linkPath)
              .each("end", function() {
                link.data([
                    [
                      [10, 40],
                      [200, 40]
                    ]
                  ])
                  .transition().duration(t).ease("linear")
                  .attr("d", linkPath)
                  .each("end", start)
              })
          })
      })
  };
  start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did try various permutations of absolute values but to no avail so that's a good breakthrough for me to see how it can work. It will help me to understand the coordinate system at play.  In your example the Gaussian filter is affecting not just the shadow but the path element as well, why is that I wonder? Why should the view box for the filter be affecting anything but the filter in the first place: in terms of the clipping and the diffusion?

Comment: It's affecting the path for me. I tried it in Chrome and FF.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean: it's working beautifully in Chrome, in windows; the vertical line doesn't render at all in IE and fails for the single horizontal line case; in FF the vertical components renders and animates beautifully, but fails for horizontal line only; Opera is the same as Chrome, although like Chrome, it fails when the vertical line has zero length, but this is only a very brief flash as it passes through that case on the way to the single line instruction case.  Try it in an IOS device (I tried Chrome and Safari) and you will see what I mean in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers behave differently when sizing the filter region. Some of them ignore stroke width - so when you get horizontal or vertical lines the filter region collapses to zero. You can fix it by specifying your filter region in userSpace units, or by putting the filter on a wrapper g element that has explicit dimensions.

Comment: I think all of then ignore stroke width don't they?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau the spec talks about the referencing element's bounding box and does not mention specific attributes like stroke. What gets me though is that the height of the bounding box is reported as zero for an horizontal line so I can't see how the 130% delivers any height at all, but it does, although not in IE which does what you would expect and collapses to zero height.

Comment: If you're going to use absolute sizes for filters, you should be sure to use filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" in your filter element - Firefox gets balky when you omit it.